# Change NSDate to Friday of that Week

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponent

Currently I have the below code to increment my days to the next friday, however what I need is to get the friday of the current week. For example if it is last Sunday, 03/01. I would expect my response to be last Friday(02/28) not Friday(03/06).

I have checked other answers but am getting confused with how to implement a clean way to accomplish this.

```
+ (NSDate *)getLastFridayYearsMonthStartingDate:(NSDate *)date {

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar gregorianCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                                                     fromDate:date];

     // Set date to last year, +1 to account for previous business day
     [dateComponents setYear: -1];
     [dateComponents setDay:[dateComponents day]+1];


    // We always want the start date to be the friday of the given week, so we will increment the difference if not
    if ([dateComponents weekday] != 6) {
        NSInteger daysToFriday = (13 - [dateComponents weekday]) % 7;
        [dateComponents setDay:[dateComponents day]+daysToFriday];
    }

    NSDate *fridayDate = [[NSCalendar gregorianCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

    return fridayDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using setWeekday to set a specific day

```
-(NSDate *) getFriday:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date];


    [comp setWeekday:6];
    [comp setHour:0];
    [comp setMinute:0];
    [comp setSecond:0];
    return [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
}
```